# get a value from another column if condition for this column is met

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get values from column 'count' and group them in the respective list based on if conditions on column 'sentiment' is met.

the table :

```
    hashtag   sentiment count
0   audi      negative  116
1   audi      neutral   885
2   audi      positive  786
6   bmw       negative  237
7   bmw       neutral   1266
8   bmw       positive  1126
32  ferrari   negative  200
33  ferrari   neutral   1175
34  ferrari   positive  910
```

desired results:

```
sent_pos  = (786, 1126, 910)
sent_neg = (116, 237, 200)
```

I've written something like this :

```
for j in car_df.iterrows():
    if car_df['sentiment'] == 'positive' :
        sent_pos = car_df.iloc[row,2]
    elif car_df['sentiment'] == 'negative' :
        sent_neg = car_df.iloc[row,2]
    else:
        sent_neutral == car_df.iloc[row,2]
return sent_pos, sent_neg, sent_neutral
```

but this error comes up:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Appreciate any help

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `groupby`, e.g:

```
g = car_df.groupby('sentiment')
return tuple(g.get_group(s)['count'].tolist() for s in ['positive', 'negative', 'neutral'])
```

Or just boolean selection:

```
return tuple(car_df[car_df['sentiment'] == s]['count'].tolist() for s in ['positive', 'negative', 'neutral'])
```